# UICollectionView not scrolling after custom UIView added to view

Tags: swift

I'm trying to add a custom UIView after adding a UICollectionView because I wanna show the custom bar view above the collection view. This is my code:

```
func loadFilters() {
    let categoriesFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    categoriesFlowLayout.scrollDirection = .vertical

    categoriesCollection = UICollectionView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: getY(yAxis: searchField) + 10, width: view.frame.size.width - 20, height: (view.frame.size.height * 9 / 10) - getY(yAxis: searchField) - 10), collectionViewLayout: categoriesFlowLayout)
    categoriesCollection.register(categoriesCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "categoriesCell")
    categoriesCollection.delegate = self
    categoriesCollection.dataSource = self
    categoriesCollection.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    categoriesCollection.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
    categoriesCollection.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
    view.addSubview(categoriesCollection)

    addBar()
    categoriesCollection.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
}
```

The `addBar()` function is declared in the custom superclass ViewController

if `addBar()` is called before `view.addSubview(categoriesCollection)` it looks like the image below but if it is called after then my collection view does not scroll or recognize touches. Is there anyway that will make the collection view scroll and bring the custom bar to front?
I've used `sendSubviewToBack()` and `bringSubviewToFront()` functions as well but the result is the same

[image: custom bar]

Comment: Run your app and click on debug view hierarchy and check if any other view resides on top of your collection view

Answer (score 0):

When you insert a view above another view, the top view gets all touch events. So the `UICollectionView` does not receive any touch events anymore since another view is above it.

As I see from your post, you just want the bar at the bottom of the screen. So check the size of your custom `UIView`. It probably fills the entire screen and is completely above the `UICollectionView`. Just give the `UIView` some sort of background color and see, how much space it fills.

If this doesn't work, you can use a `UIGestureRecognizer` on the custom `UIView` and forward the touch events to the `UICollectionView`.

Comment: Bottom bar already has a background color. If I would add a gesture recognizer I will have to add it to 18 view controllers and a lot of buttons. is there another way?

Comment: Yeah, the bottom bar has already a background color. But there is also the (<) button, which is bigger than the bar, and I believe the frame of the bottom bar view (or some view you add in the addBar() method) has a frame, which fills the entire screen. Therefore the collectionView doesn't get any touch events. Can you post the code from the addBar() method?